# Install Drush on shared hosting with SSH access?

Tags: 7, drush

I have SSH access on shared hosting and I followed this guide to install the composer: https://getcomposer.org/download/

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '669656bab3166a7aff8a7506b8cb2d1c292f042046c5a994c43155c0be6190fa0355160742ab2e1c88d40d5be660b410') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

I got the composer.phar installed/downloaded into custom dir `/composer/composer.phar`

And it works if you run it `php composer.phar`.

Then I ran `php composer.phar require drush/drush:7.x` to install drush. And it installed in the `/composer/vendor/bin`.

Now, if I run `php composer.phar drush` I get error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
  Command "drush" is not defined.
```

I set paths `PATH=$PATH:~/composer/vendor/bin` and `PATH=$PATH:~/composer/`

If I run just `composer` or `drush` I get `The program 'composer' is currently not installed. To run 'composer' please ask your administrator to install the package 'composer'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename `composer.phar` to `composer` and move it to `$HOME/bin` then make sure `$PATH` contains `$HOME/bin`. You can do that by putting the line `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin/vendor/bin` in your `.bashrc` and then doing a `source .bashrc`

Once you can run `echo $PATH` and see a string containing your home directory followed by `/bin/vendor/bin` and *if* you have moved `composer.phar` there under the name `composer` you know that the computer will look there when you run a command (`composer` for example).

The following command is what worked for me to install Drush with composer:

`composer global require drush/drush:dev-master`

Comment: It's shared hosting, I have no /bin/. Root dir contains dirs like /htdocs/, /lib/, /conf/

Comment: `$HOME/bin` means bin in your home directory.

Comment: `source .bashrc` returns `-bash: .bashrc: No such file or directory`

Comment: Okay, I had to copy .bashrc from `/etc/skel/.bashrc` to `$home` dir in order to run `source .bashrc` and now `composer` runs globally but `composer drush` reports same error.

Comment: How about: Composer require drush

Comment: @RubenBeekman http://i.imgur.com/pIb94yt.png

Comment: composer global require drush/drush:dev-master

More info: http://whaaat.com/installing-drush-9-using-composer

Be a little inventive, can't expect us to give the literal answer to every question :)

Comment: The correct solution was to add `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin/vendor/bin"` https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/2761

Answer (score 5):

you can also install manually as long as you have ssh access

```
# get drush latest 8 version
# drush 8 works with D8, D7 and D6
# https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases
wget https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/download/8.4.11/drush.phar

# make it executable
chmod +x drush.phar;

# move it to home directory or any other directory
mv drush.phar ~/drush;

# go to that directory
cd ~

# find out the path to the directory
pwd
# the output would look similar to this
# /home/your_user

# edit the following file 
nano .bashrc
# or 
# nano .bash_profile

# add this the end of the file
alias drush='/home/your_user/drush';

# use the alias you just setup
source ~/.bashrc;
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me, I only had to change the alias to alias drush='php /home/your_user/drush/drush.phar --php=/usr/bin/php'